# .htaccess redirect index.php only (exclude if variable after)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Long story short, I updated an e-commerce website but had to install the new static CMS system into a sub-directory (/wear). The main e-commerce store is still sitting in the root directory (/), and due to the large amount of products and SEO impact, I need to leave it there.

I would like to setup a requests for **just index.php** to redirect to /wear/

At the same time, if there is a request for index.php?XXXXX I would like it to still use the index.php file.

I've tried using the following .htaccess code but it's redirecting everything. Can anyone help me with this? I apologize for asking this as I know there are multiple threads, but none seemed to provide a good answer.

Attempt 1

```
RedirectMatch  /index.php https://domain/wear/
```

Attemp 2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wear/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from your `RewriteBase`. When setting it up to `/wear/`, `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` actually translates to `RewriteRule ^wear/index\.php$ - [L]` which is not really what you want.

I would try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /wear/ [L,R=301]
```

What it does is: check that the query string is empty, and if it is, redirect `index.php` (at the beginning of the request URI, so `/index.php` only) to `/wear/`

You will also need to make sure than `mod_rewrite` is active.

To do so, you can remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` parts. If `mod_rewrite` is not available, it will trigger an Error 500 as the `RewriteEngine` command will not be recognised.